# regarding sound.extract on AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, actionscript, extract

I'm now tried to use `Sound.extract()` method. It works when sound object directly load sound data using `Sound.load()`, however it does not process any information when I put sound data using `Sound.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray()`. The code is something like this:

```
var s:Sound = new Sound();
s.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,onProgress);
s.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray(bytes,8192);
bytes.position += 8192;

private function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    var num: int = s.extract(buffer,8192);
    buffer.position += num;
    s.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray(bytes,8192);
}
```

`Sound.extract()` method returns the number of data read and it's properly running when I load sound data using `Sound.load()`. However, it doesn't work (means return 0 but it doesn't throw any exception) when I load sound data using `Sound.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray()`, even it throw progress event properly ...

My question is whether or not such limitation is in AS3.

I just would like to have advice from anyone who knows a lot about AS3.

Thanks!!

Comment: Just wondering, what are you trying to accomplish? It would help to know as we might know different methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty obvious and I think you don't understand the sound.extract function properly. `sound.extract` method is to extract the raw sound data into a byte array from a valid sound file(which means the sound file should has some information).

So,
1. There is no problem in extracting the data to byte array from a sound instance which loads external sound file using `sound.load(req);` (only after the sound file is loaded) 2. Also, can extract the data into a byte array from a sound variable instantiated by a library asset `var sound:Sound = new MySound();`.

Needless to say, there should be some information to extract the data. But in this case, there is an attempt to extract the data from a variable which is just instantiated by the `Sound` class. ie) `var s:Sound = new Sound();`. There is no information to play in that but it is instantiated, so it won't throw any error while attempting to `extract`